# Notation: Indicate Non-Diagonal Entries Matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

What is the standard (or a widely used) way of indicating the non-diagonal elements of a matrix?  I'm looking for something like this.

For matrix A:
$$
A_{i,j \in i\neq j}
$$
or perhaps this:
$$ A_{i,j  :  i\neq j} $$

I am looking for a succinct way to write the equation:
$$A_{i,j \in i\neq j} = \frac{1-a}{k}$$

Comment: How about just saying what you mean?  "$A_{i,j}$ where $i\ne j$".  Or are you not allowed to use words?

Comment: i would prefer a more succinct form as it is part of a larger equation but that could work

Comment: In that case perhaps you should post the larger equation, otherwise it's hard for people to know what you really want.

Comment: Thanks, see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a case for using words IMHO.  For one thing,
$$A_{i,j \in i\neq j}$$
gives the impression that it is some sort of *modification* of the $A_{i,j}$, whereas it is in fact a *selection* of the $A_{i,j}$.  I would simply use one of the following, whichever fits better with the rest of the context:

- if $i\ne j$ then $A_{i,j} = \frac{1-a}{k}$
- $A_{i,j} = \frac{1-a}{k}$ whenever $i\ne j$

Answer (score 1):

What about $\forall$ with $:$ ?

$$A_{i,j}=\frac{{1-a}}{{k}}\qquad\forall\ i,j \in (...) \ : i\neq j $$